# Какими знаками препинания выделяется в тексте рассказ одного из героев?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, цитирование

О родителях Александра Павловича бабушка помнила очень мало. Далее — со слов Серафимы Александровны.

Папина мама. Вроде, Маланья, но я не буду врать. Высокая, худощавая. Она у нас жила. Полезла  я с печки на полку и прям ей в голову скалку-то и уронила… Ну, я маленькая была…
Или ещё история...

И далее длинная история с диалогами. Надо ли как-то выделить рассказ бабушки?
Благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

Бабушка (Серафима Александровна) не участвует в разговоре, поэтому ее слова, которые воспроизводятся в тексте, оформляются в виде цитаты.

> **3.** Если цитата состоит из нескольких абзацев, то кавычки ставят только в начале и в конце всего текста:
> *В статье «Из истории русской литературы» М. Горький писал:
>
> **«Чем же сильна литература?
>
> Насыщая идеи плотью и кровью, она даёт им большую наглядность, большую убедительность, чем философия или наука».***
> Нередко при этом для более четкого обозначения границ цитаты, особенно если внутри нее тоже имеются кавычки, используются особые полиграфические способы выделения цитаты (набор на меньший формат, набор иным шрифтом и т. д.).

Так как предполагаемый текст объемен, то для удобства чтения можно использовать отбивку, на письме — пропуск строки (после "вроде" запятая не нужна).
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
О родителях Александра Павловича бабушка помнила очень мало. Далее — со слов Серафимы Александровны:

«Папина мама. Вроде Маланья, но я не буду врать. Высокая, худощавая. Она у нас жила. Полезла я с печки на полку и прям ей в голову скалку-то и уронила… Ну, я маленькая была… Или ещё история».
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .

Вот пример из книги Е. Звездной "Шепот в темноте".

> Вспомнилось услышанное:
>
> «— Ты втянул нас в войну, Повелитель.
> — Нет. Она человек, соответственно, кровная месть невозможна. Ни один из кланов не сочтет похищение человечки достойным поводом. Войны не будет. Я обещал это, становясь во главе народа Истэка, я сдержу слово».

[Кавычки при цитатах](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=163#pp163)

Answer (score 0):

Обычно в таких случаях рассказ берут в кавычки. Можно вместо этого выделить его курсивом.